# Excel VBA: "object variable not set" but no "debug" option offered

Tags: vba, excel

Appreciating this will be a bit complicated because I don't have an exact code to show. I've been sent a web parsing VBA script that's very lengthy and works 99.99% of the cases but randomly breaks in 0.01%. In the cases where it breaks I get an Object variable not set error, however my only two options are "Okay" and "Help". Upon clicking okay the script terminates. We don't seem to know where the error stems from, which makes debugging very difficult. Debug.print would possibly help but because the breaks occur very randomly in terms of how long we need to wait for them it could be minutes or hours and there is a lot of code to test out. 
Is there an option or way to force Excel to offer the 'debug' option so I can have a look at what's wrong?

ps. Win10/Office2016 but same issue on other versions of Windows and Office. Not specific to any rows of data so I think the data that's returned from the parser may occasionally be null or something odd/unexpected/similar but I can't really check. The means of control is a hidden IE window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the VBE: *Tools > Options > General > Error Trapping* which option is checked?  "Break in class module" is a good choice.  Also - is the VB Project locked/protected?

Comment: If you can modify the code, it may help tracking where issues are by adding 2 lines for each Sub (even Function). Tedious but worth it for debugging: `Debug.Print Now, "SubOrFunctionName() Start"` right below the Sub/Function, and `Debug.Print Now, "SubOrFunctionName() Finish"` right before *End Sub/Function*. This tells you in Immediate window what subs/functions are involved and when they start and finish. So you know what takes the most waiting time. And if the Debug quits the workflow, you know which last Sub/Function is called.

Comment: @TimWilliams: at the moment it's "Unhandled Errors" only. VB Proj not protected

Comment: @PatricK - thanks, worst case that's what will happen, I'm just hoping there's some easier way around. Amusingly enough when it broke this morning it allowed me to debug so I got one element fixed but I think it will break elsewhere at some point as  there's bound to be a logic on why it usually doesn't allow (being that it breaks elsewhere)

Comment: Web parsing can be difficult to debug as it may be some objects that are having issue. May be an object isn't being returned by another object. May be search through codes with `Set `, `CreateObject(`, `New `, it may help determining what objects are involved and may get a clearer picture how it does it's job.